# How to try convert a string to a Guid

Tags: c#

I did not find the TryParse method for the Guid.  I’m wondering how others handle converting a guid in string format into a guid type.

```
Guid Id;
try
{
    Id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
}
catch
{
    Id = Guid.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 388):

```
new Guid(string)
```

You could also look at using a `TypeConverter`.

Comment: Specifically, a GUIDConverter, which is built in.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.guidconverter.aspx

Comment: TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Guid))

Comment: @leppie can you tell me the pros and cons of using GUID as string rather then using as DataTyps GUID

Comment: I can tell you example:

@cracker When you are making API and you wanna filter something by Guid (since its primary key in a table) what will you send from the front in a request? Most likely a string in URL, but on back in the controller you would most like wanna use it as Guid. As for speed comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713109/performance-using-guid-object-or-guid-string-as-key

Comment: I would recommend @juFo answer with `TryParse()` or `TryParseExact()`. If you supply an invalid Guid you will get the following exception when trying to access it in a comparison or similar otherwise: FormatException: `Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).`

Answer (score 150):

use code like this:

```
new Guid("9D2B0228-4D0D-4C23-8B49-01A698857709")
```

instead of "9D2B0228-4D0D-4C23-8B49-01A698857709" you can set your string value

Answer (score 35):

```
Guid.TryParse()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse

or

```
Guid.TryParseExact()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparseexact

in .NET 4.0 (or 3.5?)

Comment: I had been using Guid.Parse, but I see Guid.TryParse will return a boolean indicating if it was successful. That would be better.

Answer (score 8):

This will get you pretty close, and I use it in production and have never had a collision.  However, if you look at the constructor for a guid in reflector, you will see all of the checks it makes.

```
 public static bool GuidTryParse(string s, out Guid result)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && guidRegEx.IsMatch(s))
        {
            result = new Guid(s);
            return true;
        }

        result = default(Guid);
        return false;
    }

    static Regex guidRegEx = new Regex("^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|" +
                          "^({|\\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\\))?$|" +
                          "^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: This regex matches on "92841CDF-734C-46b4-A40C-53B8B59947AA}" which is invalid because of missing bracket. Anyone know a way to change this regex to not match for this case?

Comment: @Maggie you could duplicate the regex, once with the brackets, once without - so it's either/or.

Comment: Never ever use a regex when there is another solution available.

Comment: @NickN. This post was from 2008, at the time there was no Guid.TryParse

Comment: @BrianRudolph fair enough :) Excuse me. Perhaps update your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a TryParse() equivalent.  If you create a new instance of a System.Guid and pass the string value in, you can catch the three possible exceptions it would throw if it is invalid.

Those are:

- ArgumentNullException
- FormatException
- OverflowException

I have seen some implementations where you can do a regex on the string prior to creating the instance, if you are just trying to validate it and not create it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is some very basic error checking, you could just check the length of the string.

```
              string guidStr = "";
              if( guidStr.Length == Guid.Empty.ToString().Length )
                 Guid g = new Guid( guidStr );
```