# ASP.NET core Identity - by default why are the database primary key defined "nvarchar" and not "UniqueIdentifier"?

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, sqldatatypes

By default ASP.NET Identity uses GUID for the primary key, however when the database primary key is generated it uses nvarchar - why doesnt it use SQL Data type "UniqueIdentifier"?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make EF-Core use a Guid instead of String for its ID/Primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166098/how-to-make-ef-core-use-a-guid-instead-of-string-for-its-id-primary-key)

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate, the question was why not how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why is because the Id property type is a string. In fact all of the primary keys in asp.net core identity are strings with their constructors looking like this...

```
public IdentityUser()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Now the exact reason why is because EF runs on multiple database providers and not all of them have a GUID type. GUID types are quicker as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713117/5107677), but unless your working with a huge dataset and need top of the line performance, string type works just fine