# How to get a Hardware ID as GUID format in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, guid

I am developing a Windows Store app (a.k.a metro app). I need to get the Machine ID as GUID format.

I have this code:

```
var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
var hardwareId = token.Id;
byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
String machineId = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
```

machineId is a string , but it does not match a GUID. Someone knows how to convert this value in a GUID format ?

Comment: Can you post a sample string value? Why do you need to convert to a GUID?

Comment: It just isn't a GUID.  It also changes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Comment: Ok. I need to convert to GUID because I have to call a legacy service that receive a GUID as machine ID. I understand that the string is not a GUID but I could take some bytes groups to build a GUID with them. For example I could take Processor+Memory+BIOS etc to make a GUID and send this to my service

Comment: Does it need to survive an app uninstall and reinstall? If not, you could just generate a Guid, store it in local storage and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It is based on the code from another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350500/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-guid).

```
    private async void  Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
        String machineId = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);


        Guid guid;

        bool isDataAVailale = GuidTryParse(machineId, out guid);

        myText.Text = guid.ToString();

    }


    public static bool GuidTryParse(string s, out Guid result)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && guidRegEx.IsMatch(s))
        {
            result = new Guid(s);
            return true;
        }

        result = default(Guid);
        return false;
    }

    static Regex guidRegEx = new Regex("^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|" +
                          "^({|\\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\\))?$|" +
                          "^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```