# How to convert string to Guid

Tags: c#, guid

I have a string variable which is receiving a `Guid`. I need to convert this string back to Guid as the database field is of type `Guid`.

I tried using:

```
Guid myGuid = Guid.Empty;;
myGuid = Guid.Parse(myId);
```

But keep getting `Format Exception; Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)`.

Below is my code:

```
 public string addVehicleDetails(string vname, string vtype, string regNumber, string ftype, string fefficiency, string insby, DateTime datecreated, string myId)
        {

            string result = string.Empty;
            tblVehicleDetail myVehicleDetails = new tblVehicleDetail();
          //  Guid myGuid = Guid.Empty;
            System.Guid myGuid = new Guid(myId);
           // myGuid = Guid.Parse(myId);
            try {

               // Add details into vehicle details
                myVehicleDetails.VehicleName = vname;
                myVehicleDetails.VehicleType = vtype;
                myVehicleDetails.RegistrationNumber = regNumber;
                myVehicleDetails.FuelType = ftype;
                myVehicleDetails.FuelEfficiency = fefficiency;
                myVehicleDetails.InsuranceBy = insby;

                myVehicleDetails.DateCreated = datecreated;
                myVehicleDetails.Guid = myGuid;

                dc.tblVehicleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(myVehicleDetails);

                dc.SubmitChanges();

                return result = vname;

            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                exp.ToString();
                return result = "Error in Adding Vehicle Details.";
            }
        }
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Please show examples and code, because `Guid.Parse` does exactly what you want. There seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Did you check the value of myId? Is it in right format?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350500/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-guid

Comment: Please post examples of myId. what are the values you try to parse?

Comment: please post value of myId

Comment: @Trupti Can you provide code where you are converting `Guid` to string or string value .

Comment: This question in already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/c-test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350500/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-guid

Comment: @Trupti If you can just show your string which is causing error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Format Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells you that your input(`String myId`) is not in a recognized format.

You should handle exceptions clearly your input string format is incorrect so use `Guid.TryParse`(This method returns false if input is null or not in a recognized format, and does not throw an exception.) . [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.Tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also check for [Guid.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact.aspx) method .

```
  myGuid = Guid.Parse(myId); 
  if (Guid.TryParse(myId, out newGuid))
    {
     try 
      { 
       myVehicleDetails.DateCreated = datecreated; 
       myVehicleDetails.Guid = myGuid; 
       dc.tblVehicleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(myVehicleDetails); 
       dc.SubmitChanges(); 
       } 
     }
     else
      {
        //Input string is not in correct format
      }
```

Comment: after trying this i could execute else block i.e input string was not in correct format

Comment: @Trupti You should check your input string format, Go through this you can specify format of input parameter in your case your `myID` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact.aspx

Comment: actually while getting the string it is coming with slashes like "\"********-****-****-****-************\"" may be because of that i am facing the problem

Comment: @Trupti Please post your code where you are initializing your `Guid` and converting it to string . and please post your string value.Otherwise it's just a wild-goose chase.

Comment: okkk ... i could find what was going wrong ..it was because of those slashes ...once i remove those slashes i can get the output properly. this code is correct to convert string to Guid myGuid = Guid.Parse(myId);